# Crystal Reports group name error

Tags: date, crystal-reports

I am grouping on a date field. The tree explorer for the report when data is displayed shows the date as 3 days before the date that is in the records. The detail in the report lists the correct date. I have verified the field shown in the report and the Group field are pointing to the same database-table-field. I have also set the format so that only the the actual date info is being used  ie no time info. The dates shown in the Group field name do not even exist in the the table - filed being examined nor any where else in the database (ORACLE 10).

Answer (score 0):

I don't have CR in front of me, but there is formatting on the group that is causing this.  Something like show by week instead of the actual date.  I've had this bite me numerous times.  I can be more specific when I get to work tomorrow.

**Edited to add**:  On the insert group dialog, you need to change:

"*The section will be printed: for each week*" to "*for each day*".